# How to work out z-score normalisation?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, normalization, standardized

I am confused as how to do z-score normalisation. I have found the equation to do this, required the mean and standard deviation, but I'm not sure how to work this out given my situation.

I have 2 classifiers in my system. To use the scores together, I know that I need to normalise them because they will differ in scales, etc. I wish to use z-score normalisation for this. My question is, given the 2 scores from the two classifiers, what do I need to do with the scores to z-score normalise them? I want to able to combine/compare them.

My (probably flawed!) understanding is that for a classifier score set we use the mean and the standard deviation. But we can't always assume we will already have a score set to get the mean and standard deviation from, can we?

Answer (score 0):

To compute the z-scores of a given set of numbers you need to compute the sample mean and the sample deviation. From each score subtract the mean and divide the standard deviation. 
Consider the set of numbers below where each observation is test scores ranging  from 0 to 100.

```
{40, 50, 60, 55, 70, 80, 90}
```

If you wanted to compare them another set of test scores where the test scores ranged from 0 to 250 such as:

```
{100, 115, 214, 50, 200, 80, 90}
```

You couldn't directly compare the compare them. I.e. a score of 80 in the second set is clearly worse than than 80 in the first set (80/250 vs 80/100). One way to do this is using z-scores. They are computing as follows:

1. Find the mean

   mean of the first set is:   63.57143
   mean of the second set is:  121.2857
2. Subtract the sample mean from each score. This will give you a set of numbers that are centered on zero.

   {-23.571429, -13.571429,  -3.571429,  -8.571429,  6.428571,  16.428571,  26.428571}
   {-21.285714,  -6.285714,  92.714286, -71.285714, 78.714286, -41.285714, -31.285714}
3. Compute the standard deviation from the original set and divide the "centered" scores by that number:

   Set 1 sigma = 17.49149

   Set 2 sigma = 61.98041

This is computed to be:

{-1.3475937, -0.7758873, -0.2041809. -0.4900341,  0.3675256,  0.9392320,  1.5109384}
{-0.3434265, -0.1014145,  1.4958643, -1.1501330,  1.2699865, -0.6661091, -0.5047678}

Now you have two sets of numbers are directly comparable. A value of zero means that it is the set's average value. A value of 1 standard deviation above the set's average. A value of -1 means that its is one standard deviation below the average and so on.

Comment: Thank you. But in my problem, I ask how I can do this given I get 2 classifier scores? How can I compute a mean from two classifier scores alone? I can't generate *n* scores to normalise them, I wish to compare the 2 scores immediately.